# Access to different versions of taskmgr.exe for analysis

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, add-on, taskmanager, patch

I'm looking to get hold of different versions of taskmgr.exe from different versions of Windows, in order to test a Task Manager addon I'm building. I've managed to get some basic additional functionality into the Win7 version, but I need access to other copies so I can test on those too.

I don't need a copy of the entire OS (otherwise I'd grab the compat VHDs from Microsoft), since my reverse engineering skills are good enough to write static patches without a debugger, so just the actual taskmgr.exe files will do the job.

I've got the Win7 Ultimate x64 and Vista x86 versions from two Windows installs here, but I can't find any repository online where I can get hold of other versions from different major versions, service packs, etc.

What's my best bet here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you cannot do this (legally) without obtaining legal copies of all the Windows versions concerned. taskmgr.exe is pretty much the core functionality and cannot be obtained separately.

In general the only exceptions to this rule are the so-called `redestributables` which can be bundled with 3rd party applications. Task Manager is not one of them.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I could borrow some friends' machines and do the work on there.

Comment: @Polynomial: BTW, I believe MSDN subscription provides access to multiple Windows version for evaluation purposes. IANAL and don't know whether these can legally be used for your purposes.